# Complex query in Zend 1.12

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to obtain the same result of this query below in Zend 1.12.

```
    SELECT te.id_usuario, u.nome, te.id_texto, t.titulo 
    FROM usuarios u, tex_turmas_alunos ta, tex_testes te, tex_textos t, publicacoes p
    WHERE te.id_usuario=u.id 
        and u.id=ta.id_aluno and ta.id_turma=10
        and te.id_texto=t.id
        and te.acertou = 'sim'
        and ta.ativo='sim'
        and te.id_texto=p.id_texto and p.id_turma=ta.id_turma
    GROUP BY te.id_usuario, t.id
    ORDER BY u.nome, t.titulo
```

Here is my code:

1:

```
$select = 
$this -> getAdapter()
-> select()
-> from(array('u' => "usuarios"), array("nome" => "u.nome"))
-> join(array( 'ta' => 'tex_turmas_alunos'), "ta.ativo = 'sim' AND ud.id = ta.id_aluno",    null )
-> join(array('te' => 'tex_testes'), "te.acertou = 'sim'", array('te.id_texto',   'te.id_usuario'))
-> join(array('t' => 'tex_textos'), 'te.id_texto = t.id', array('t.titulo'))
-> join(array('p' => 'publicacoes'), 'p.id_turma = ta.id_turma', null )
-> where('ta.id_turma = '10')
-> group(array('te.id_usuario', 't.id' ))
-> order(array('u.nome', 't.titulo'));

return  $this ->getAdapter ()->fetchAll ( $select );
```

2:

```
    $sqlString = 
    "SELECT te.id_usuario, u.nome, te.id_texto, t.titulo 
    FROM usuarios u, tex_turmas_alunos ta, tex_testes te, tex_textos t, publicacoes p
    WHERE te.id_usuario=u.id 
        and u.id=ta.id_aluno and ta.id_turma= ?
        and te.id_texto=t.id
        and te.acertou = 'sim'
        and ta.ativo='sim'
        and te.id_texto=p.id_texto and p.id_turma=ta.id_turma
    GROUP BY te.id_usuario, t.id
    ORDER BY u.nome, t.titulo"; 
    $sql = $this->getAdapter()->query($sqlString, '10');
```

The result of the first query is:

```
    SELECT `u`.`nome`, `te`.`id_texto`, `te`.`id_usuario`, `t`.`titulo` FROM `usuarios` AS `u` INNER JOIN `tex_turmas_alunos` AS `ta` ON ta.ativo = 'sim' AND ta.id_aluno = u.id INNER JOIN `tex_testes` AS `te` ON te.acertou = 'sim' INNER JOIN `tex_textos` AS `t` ON te.id_texto = t.id INNER JOIN `publicacoes` AS `p` ON p.id_turma = ta.id_turma WHERE (ta.id_turma = '11') GROUP BY `te`.`id_usuario`, `t`.`id` ORDER BY `u`.`nome` ASC, `t`.`titulo` ASC
```

This result doesn't the correct return. What's wrong with my query?

--
The wrong result is like this:

```
nome                  id_texto id_usuario titulo
Another person          182      116       t2
Another person          183      18        t3
Another person          183      14        t3
Another person          183      24        t3
Another person          183      33        t3
Another person          183      19        t3
Another person          183      10        t3
```

The result that I expect:

```
id_usuario     nome     id_texto     titulo
   108       Person 1      131       Text A
   108       Person 1      132       Text B
   108       Person 1      166       Text C
   108       Person 1      304       Text D
```

Do you understand the diference? They're two completely different results.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors returned? Maybe active them?

Comment: In the first query, no errors, but doesn't show the same result. In the second, I've got this error: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo could not be converted to string

Comment: Can you provide the result of the first query and the expected results?

Comment: Those queries are not identical. One time you used 'JOIN' to join tables; And the other time you used where clause. They should'nt be identical queries

Comment: How can I use multiples tables in FROM clause? I tried something like this: from(array('u' => "usuarios", "ta" => "tex_turmas_alunos")... but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is my fixed function. Works great.

```
public function testesCorretos($id_turma){

        $sqlString = 
                "SELECT te.id_usuario,  u.nome, u.matricula, te.id_texto, t.titulo 
                FROM usuarios u, tex_turmas_alunos ta, tex_testes te, tex_textos t, publicacoes p
                WHERE te.id_usuario=u.id 
                  and u.id=ta.id_aluno 
                  and te.id_texto=t.id
                  and te.acertou = 'sim'
                  and ta.ativo='sim'
                  and te.id_texto=p.id_texto 
                  and p.id_turma=ta.id_turma
                  and ta.id_turma= ?
                GROUP BY te.id_usuario, t.id
                ORDER BY u.nome, t.titulo"; 

        $sql = $this->getAdapter()->query($sqlString, $id_turma);

        while($rows = $sql->fetchAll() ){           
            for($i =0; $i <= count($rows); $i++){
                $row[] =  array(
                        'id' => $rows[$i]['id_usuario'],
                        'nome' => $rows[$i]['nome'],
                        'matricula' =>  $rows[$i]['matricula'],
                        'id_texto' => $rows[$i]['id_texto'],
                        'titulo' => $rows[$i]['titulo']
                );
            }
        }

        return $row;

    }
```